# application not working on OSX 10.5

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I am developing an application to work on Mac OSX 10.5 and later and I am using Mac running 10.6.4 with Xcode 3.2.4. The application is very simple which accepts some information from user and stores it in a file. The application working perfectly on OSX 10.6 but on OSX 10.5.8 when I double click on it to open it does not start at all. In project settings I have base SDK set to 10.5, architectures -> standard 32/64 bit Universal, GCC 4.0 and in info.plist file I have set LSMinimumSystemVersion key to '10.5.0' but still application is not running on OSX 10.5.8. What am I doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.
Console Log: [image]

Is this of any help?

Comment: There's no way to answer your question without taking many wild guesses. Have you checked the console log for messages from your app? If so, post them with your question.

Comment: Looks more like a permission denied problem. Have you tried to copy your entire app locally on your second machine (as it seems to be running from a Dropbox mount point)?

Comment: Dropbox just uses a plain old folder. The problem is the DropBox service itself doesn't fully support syncing file permissions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're sharing the app bundle via DropBox.

[Per their support forum](http://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=16897), DropBox does not properly support permissions. This screws up the permissions on app bundles. Zip the app before sharing on DropBox.

Comment: Do you mean active configuration: release? Then yes.

Comment: DO you mean cntl+click-get info- sharing & permissions, then yes. I have set the privileges to Read & Write for all users. Am I messing it up somewhere in code?

Comment: This isn't a code problem at all.  It's a problem with Dropbox.  Instead of dragging the app into Dropbox and trying to run it from there, you need to zip it on your development machine (right-click on your mac.app icon from the Finder, then select 'Compress "mac.app"'), put the resulting mac.app.zip file into Dropbox, and then on your test machine, copy the mac.app.zip file to your Desktop and double-click to unzip the mac.app file.  At that point, you should be able to double-click your mac.app icon to run it.

Comment: It worked ! thanks a lot people. I guess it was a problem of technology over-use! :)

Comment: Be wary in general of any syncing service, file sharing service, or e-mail system. Always zip application bundles up prior to transmission as most systems don't handle the specifics of Apple app bundles with any semblance of grace.